# AMQP-CPP > Bad file descriptor in handler

Tags: c++, boost, rabbitmq, boost-asio, amqp

I am trying to use [AMQP-CPP](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP) library for messaging, however I can not make it work. I want to use already built classes from the library for channel, connection, handler. I started with their examples but every time running the code I get `Bad file descriptor` error and process ends. My code looks like this

```
#include <amqpcpp.h>
#include <amqpcpp/libboostasio.h>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>

class MyHandler : public AMQP::LibBoostAsioHandler
{
public:
    MyHandler(boost::asio::io_service& service)
        : AMQP::LibBoostAsioHandler(service)
    {
    }

    virtual void onError(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection, const char *message) override
    {
        std::cout << "MyHandler::onError " << message << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // access to the event loop
    boost::asio::io_service service(2);

    // handler for libevent
    MyHandler handler(service);

    // make a connection
    AMQP::TcpConnection connection(&handler, AMQP::Address("amqp://localhost/"));

    // we need a channel too
    AMQP::TcpChannel channel(&connection);

    channel.onError([](const char *message) {
        // report error
        std::cout << "channel error: " << message << std::endl;
    });
    channel.onReady([]() {
        // send the first instructions (like publishing messages)
        std::cout << "channel onReady: " << std::endl;
    });

    // create a temporary queue
    channel.declareQueue("aaa").onSuccess([&connection](const std::string& name, uint32_t messagecount, uint32_t consumercount) {

        // report the name of the temporary queue
        std::cout << "declared queue " << name << std::endl;

        // now we can close the connection
        connection.close();
    });  

    auto startCb = [](const std::string &consumertag) {
        std::cout << "consume operation started" << std::endl;
    };

    // callback function that is called when the consume operation failed
    auto errorCb = [](const char *message) {
        std::cout << "consume operation failed" << std::endl;
    };

    // callback operation when a message was received
    auto messageCb = [&channel](const AMQP::Message &message, uint64_t deliveryTag, bool redelivered) {
        std::cout << "message received" << std::endl;
        // acknowledge the message
        channel.ack(deliveryTag);
    };

    channel.consume("aaa").onReceived(messageCb)
    .onSuccess(startCb)
    .onError(errorCb);

    // run the loop
    service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> MyHandler::onError Bad file descriptor

Also, error occurs on the line `service.run();`

I have also tried a similar thing with `libevent`.

What's wrong here and how to fix? Any ideas?

Comment: Is the connection attempt logged in RabbitMQ? Do you see anything else interesting in the RabbitMQ logs? Have you tried running a TCP capture on port 5672 to see if anything is happening there?

Comment: @LukeBakken that was the only log that I wrote in the question, nothing more. I just tried to camputer 5672 port and nothing happened while running the code.

Comment: The problem was resolved here https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP/issues/244

Comment: @nabroyan please consider self-answering this post. That would make this post more useful to others on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it turned out that there are two issues.

Firstly, `libev` should be used, because that's the oficial supported one. Secondly, make sure that your RabbitMQ server is running. More detailed information you can find [here](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP/issues/244).

Comment: Actually I am solving the same problem. Is this example working on windows? Or I need to program entire networking layer in handler?

Comment: I don't remember the details already, but as far as I recall, this was running on Linux and I created a small wrapper library based on this (like a networking layer) to use in my program.